# MLT Producer with infinite color:black

Tags: mlt

i want create multicam view and place each stream like mosaic.
I use "color:black" producer for background and set in_and_out like -1 -1.
It's work for me, but after 10 minutes producer ends and mProd1 set to fullscreen.
How to make "color:black" producer infinite?

Code sample:

```
Producer blackBg(*T_Profile, "color:black");
blackBg.set_in_and_out(-1, -1);
Producer mProd1(*T_Profile, "udp://224.224.224.224:1234");
Tractor *mTractor = new Tractor();
mTractor->set_track( blackBg, 0);
mTractor->set_track( mProd1, 1);
Transition mix1(*T_Profile, "composite");
mix1.set("start","0%/0%:50%x50%");
mTractor->plant_transition(mix1, 0, 1);
T_Consumer->connect(*mTractor);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make it infinite, but you can make it very, very long: 2147483648 frames (2^31). Even at 60 fps, that is over a year: 2^31/60/(60*60*24) = 414 days. You must set the length property before set_in_and_out(). The base producer (mlt_producer) defaults to 15000 frames unless the producer (e.g. avformat and decklink) set a different length.

```
blackBg.set("length", 2**31)
```